# Angular 9 routing to child component in lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular9

I have problem with routing setup to child component in a lazy loaded module.

app.routing.ts

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'admin',
        loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule),
    },
];
```

admin.routing.ts

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: AdminPanelComponent,

        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'user/list',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'user/list',
                canActivate: [AdminGuard],
                component: UserListComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'user/new',
                canActivate: [AdminGuard],
                component: UserComponent,
            }
        ]
    }

];
```

When I go to https://localhost/admin app is not redirected to https://localhost/admin/user/list as expected but to https://localhost.

AdminPanelComponent is a UI layout component for admin module.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:
Same problem with lazy loaded module without child components

app.routing.ts

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'agent',
        loadChildren: () => import('./agent/agent.module').then(m => m.AgentModule),
    },
];
```

agent.routing.ts

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: AgentPanelComponent,
    },

];
```

When I go to https://localhost/agent app is redirected to https://localhost.

UPDATE:
I found a problem and fixed it but can't explain why it was not working.

app.routing.ts

```
export const routes: Routes = [
        {
            path: 'auth',
            loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule),
        },
        {
            path: 'admin',
            loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule),
        },
        {
            path: 'agent',
            loadChildren: () => import('./agent/agent.module').then(m => m.AgentModule),
        },

    ];
```

Both admin and agent modules are using auth module.

auth.routing.ts

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        canActivate: [RedirectIfLoggedInGuard],
        component: LoginPageComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'password-reset',
        canActivate: [RedirectIfLoggedInGuard],
        component: LoginPasswordResetComponent
    },
];
```

In auth.routing.ts I've changed `path` from this

```
{
            path: '',
            canActivate: [RedirectIfLoggedInGuard],
            component: LoginPageComponent
        },
```

to this

```
{
            path: 'login',
            canActivate: [RedirectIfLoggedInGuard],
            component: LoginPageComponent
        },
```

And it's working fine now.

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example on https://stackblitz.com ?

Answer (score 4):

I have solved your problem in below stackBlitz, there are many ways it can go wrong. so instead of I explaining it all, can you have a look at this implementation?

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j1s19b

also ask if you have any particular problem in comment below, I'll try to help you there.

If it solves your problem. please mark this answer as accepted for what it's worth .

Comment: It must be something else in my code... Your solution is the same as mine and yours is working fine.

Comment: Can you check the RouterModule imports in both the modules

Comment: also you must be getting some sort of error in the console window of your browser.

Comment: can you share it?

Comment: Yes in app.module.ts I have RouterModule.forRoot(routes), in admin.module.ts     RouterModule.forChild(routes). No errors in console, just warning: "Throttling navigation to prevent the browser from hanging. See https://crbug.com/882238. Command line switch --disable-ipc-flooding-protection can be used to bypass the protection"

Comment: one thing you can do to understand what's happening is put `enableTracing = true` like this, RouterModuule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true });

Comment: This problem usually occurs where there is possibility for some infinity loop, because of the ways routes are configured

Comment: Found a solution (updated question), but can't explain why it was not working

Comment: Awesome, it's most likely because of recursive routing. anyways can you upvote my answer I am trying to build my reputation, just a little favor 

Answer (score 0):

What you probably did and created the infinite recursion is you imported AuthModule inside the AdminModule which in turn mounted the routes for the login in the admin module. To confirm the issue try navigating to /admin/login. You will see that it will load up the LoginComponent which is not what you expected to happen. The reason you probably created the infinite recursion is because your guard is now running both on /login routes and /admin routes which tries to redirect to itself.

Answer (score -1):

In admin.routing.ts you need to make sure you add: `RouterModule.forChild(routes)` in the `imports`.

In app.routing.ts you need to add `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)`

Comment: This was not the problem, all my imports were fine. Please see my updated question for solution